# ios - UITableViewCell does not fill the entire width of the table

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I think the cells don't fill the parent width because of indicated dimensions 300x300, but I don't know how to change it to parent size.

[image]

[image]

TableView has constraints on the boundaries of the device. I also tried set constraints for the cell but it didn't help.

[image]

Comment: You need to give constraints to your image view (as well as the other elements) in your cell.

Comment: Why don't you set constraint too into the UITableViewCell Xib ?

Comment: @Larme adding constraints in the UITableViewCell xib is not possible for me. See 
 ibb.co/N99Q6D7

Answer (score 0):

You should set constraints in your image and on entire UITableViewCell xib just like in ViewController

Comment: Adding constraints in the UITableViewCell xib is not possible for me. See https://ibb.co/N99Q6D7

Comment: Try to set constraints in UIImageView and other components

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic design task. You really should take the time to go through a few tutorials on Auto-Layout.

The comment you posted: *"Adding constraints in the UITableViewCell xib is not possible for me,"* along with the image, indicates you are selecting the `Content View` in your cell xib, but that is ***not*** where you want to add constraints.

You need to constrain the elements in your cell ***to*** the content view:

[image]

which results in a table view (at run-time) that looks like this:

[image]